# Add CSV file to PostgreSQL using QGIS

Tags: qgis, dbmanager

I have a CSV file. I would like have this file inside GeoServer. I used "add postgis layers" in QGIS and I added the connection that I have in  PgAdmin III. I had the message that the connection is succesful.

I added the CSV file using "DBManager" in QGIS. The problem is that the section "public" inside "DBManager" is red (means error) and I don't have the CSV in PgAdmin III.

This is the error that I had[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshot to your post? I'm not sure about "The problem is that the section "public" inside "DBManager" is red (means error) ".

Comment: Did you add a CSV to PostgreSQL, or did you *convert* the file to a table? Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact procedure.

Comment: Hi @laura just to be clear. You've opened the csv in qgis, created the connection to postgis and now you want to export that csv into the postgis database?